# Почему не работает счетчик?

Tags: javascript

Получается так что у каждого продукта одинаковое количество

```js
const counterProduct = (item) => {
    const basketLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('basket'));

    let counterProduct = 1;
    basketLocalStorage.find((item) => {
        counterProduct++
    })

    return counterProduct;
}

arrBasketProducts.forEach((item) => {
    let counter = counterProduct(item);
    createBasketCard(item, productContainer,counter)
})

const createBasketCard = (item, parent,counter) => {
    const productCard = document.createElement(`div`);
    productCard.classList.add(`productBasket__item`);

    productCard.innerHTML = `
        <div class="productBasket__img-container" data-id=${item.id}>
                <img src="${item.img}" alt="" class="productBasket__img">
        </div>
        <div class="productBasket__content" data-id=${item.id}>
        <h3 class="productBasket__title">
            ${item.name}
        </h3>
        <p class="productBasket__counter-container">
            <span class="productBasket__counter-title">Количество:</span>
            <span class="productBasket__counter-counter" id="counter">${counter}</span>
        </p>
        <p class="productBasket__price">
            ${item.price} грн
        </p>
        <div class="productBasket__buttons">
            <button class="productBasket__btnDelete btn btn--black" id="basketDeleteItemBtn" data-id="${item.id}">Убрать из корзины</button>
        </div>
    `;

    parent.appendChild(productCard);
}

"basketArr": [
        {
            "id": 11,
            "name": "Опасная Бритва The Bluebeards Revenge «Claymore» Straight Razor 5/8",
            "price":"5778",
            "descriptions": "Классическая бритва со сверх-острым лезвиem",
            "brand": "Claymore",
            "img":"https://barbercompany.com/image/cache/webp/catalog/product/2016-06-the-bluedeards-            revange-claymore-straight-razor-543x543.webp"
        },
        {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "Дорожный Набор Для Бритья Edwin Jagger Ejlt2M3",
            "price":"4188",
            "descriptions":"Дорожный набор для бритья от Edwin Jagger.",
            "brand": "Edwin Jagger",
            "img":"https://barbercompany.com/image/cache/webp/catalog/product/2015-11-294-543x543.webp"
        },
]
```

Comment: Можете добавить данные для примера. Чтоб можно было воспроизвести код ?

Comment: Приведите код в рабочее состояние.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const counterProduct = (item) => {
    const basketLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('basket'));

    let counterProduct = 0;
    
    basketLocalStorage.forEach((product) => {
        if(item.id === product.id) {
            counterProduct++;
        }
    })

    return counterProduct ;
}
```

Comment: Нашел другое решение проблемы.